# Why does not the following code snippet run successfully?

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning

I was reading Programming Collective Intelligence,chapter on Search Engines where I came across the following piece of code and upon implementation,it gave me error.Please Help.

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import *
from urlparse import urljoin

class crawler:
def __init__(self,dbname):
    pass

def __del__(self):
    pass
def dbcommit(self):
    pass

def getentryid(self,table,field,value,createnew=True):
    return None

def addtoindex(self,url,soup):
    print 'Indexing %s' % url

def gettextonly(self,soup):
    return None

def seperatewords(self,text):
    return None

def isindexed(self,url):
    return False

def addlinkref(self,urlFrom,urlTo,linkText):
    pass

def crawl(self,pages,depth=2):
    for i in range(depth):
        newpages=set()
        for page in pages:
            try:
                c=urllib2.urlopen(page)
            except:
                print 'Could not open %s'%page
                continue
            soup=BeautifulSoup(c.read())
            self.addtoindex(page,soup)

            links=soup('a')
            for link in links:
                if('href' in dict(link.attrs)):
                    url=urljoin(page,link['href'])
                    if url.find("'")!=-1: continue
                    url=url.split('#')[0]
                    if url[0:4]=='http' and not self.isindexed(url):
                        newpages.add(url)
                    linkText=self.gettextonly(link)
                    self.addlinkref(page,url,linkTest)
                self.dbcommit()
            pages=newpages


def createindextables(self):
    pass
```

I got the following error:

```
>>cwlr.crawl(pagelist)
Indexing http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-97778b0c0db8> in <module>()
----> 1 cwlr.crawl(pagelist)

C:\Users\Blue\Anaconda\searchengine.py in crawl(self, pages, depth)
     47                                                 url=urljoin(page,link['href'])
     48                                                 if url.find("'")!=-1: continue
---> 49                                                 url=url.split('#')[0]
     50                                                 if url[0:4]=='http' and not      self.isindexed(url):
 51                                                         newpages.add(url)

NameError: global name 'linkTest' is not defined
```

Comment: You changed the source code without restarting the interpreter. The traceback source code does *not* match the actual bytecode being executed (there is no name `linkTest` on that line).

Comment: Even after restarting it is not working.

Comment: Perhaps you have stale bytecode somewhere then; check if there is a `C:\Users\Blue\Anaconda\searchengine.pyc` or `C:\Users\Blue\Anaconda\searchengine.pyo` file and remove it.

Comment: Or did the error message change?

Comment: I had .pyc file in the path you mentioned and deleted it.Restarted the Kernel(I use IPython),still get the same error.

Comment: In fact I had .pyc files in C:\Users\Blue\Anaconda\Lib\idlelib as well as C:\Users\Blue\Anaconda\Lib\idlelib\idle_test.Should I delete these too?

Comment: No, I named a specific file. But the error message doesn't match your actual error as pointed out by NPE below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> NameError: global name 'linkTest' is not defined

You've misspelt `linkText` as `linkTest`:

```
linkText=self.gettextonly(link)
      ↑
self.addlinkref(page,url,linkTest)
                               ↑
```

Comment: There is no correlation with the error message posted however.